# How do you say the scientific version of singularity?

Tags: vocabulaire, terminologie, science

How do you say the scientific version of singularity, like the infinitely dense center of a black hole?

Comment: Do you mean, what's the french scientific term for "singularity", i.e. a translation that wouldn't be in layman terms ? As far as I know : [*singularité (gravitationnelle)*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singularit%C3%A9_gravitationnelle).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Same word applies: "**une singularité**". You may use "une singularité gravitationnelle" when you are talking about a "trou noir".

When talking about singular functions, in a broader sense, I am trying to promote the nice French word of   "*affût*"  (in  similarity to "sharp"), but without much success so far.